# Am I canceling coroutines correctly

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel, kotlin-coroutines

I have my view model as such

```
class StorageValidationViewModel: ViewModel(), CoroutineScope {

    //Coroutines
    private val _job = SupervisorJob()
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = Dispatchers.Main + _job

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        coroutineContext.cancel()
    }
    ......
}
```

I have some methods that make a network call via `Retrofit` that start a coroutine

```
fun getStorageLocations(){
        launch {
            var locations:List<StorageLocationData>? = null
            try {
                locations = _storageLocationRepository.getAllStorageLocations()
            }catch (e:IOException){
                e.printStackTrace()
            }

            storageLocationsLiveData.postValue(locations)
        }
    }
```

Everything works fine but I have a feeling that I am not canceling the coroutines correctly when the ViewModel is getting cleared because I dont actually use `coroutineContext` anywhere thus creating a memory leak

should I be doing

```
launch(coroutineContext){
    //API call?
}
```

or is what I am doing fine? I just want to make sure I am not creating memory leaks with what I am doing

Comment: `launch` is extension method of `CoroutineScope`, which your `ViewModel` implements so it looks fine. Other issue is that unless your `getAllStorageLocations` is suspending method, it might not be aware of cancellation and will keep executing regardless.

Comment: @Pawel yes `getAllStorageLocations` is a `suspend fun` because the retrofit api uses `await` when making the call

Comment: Everything is correct

Answer (score 0):

You don't create memory leaks with your implementation. `coroutineContext: CoroutineContext` is a property which must be implemented when inheriting from `CoroutineScope`. When launching a coroutine using `launch` coroutine builder it uses overridden `coroutineContext` context, so you don't need to pass it explicitly to the `launch()` builder.

There is more straightforward way to use coroutines in a `ViewModel`. [`viewModelScope`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#viewmodelscope) property can be used to launch a coroutine without inheriting from `CoroutineScope`:

```
class MyViewModel: ViewModel() {
    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            // Coroutine that will be canceled when the ViewModel is cleared.
        }
    }
}
```

And no need to cancel the job explicitly in `onCleared()` method.

For `viewModelScope`, use `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.0` or higher.